# Upload Excel data to MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, openpyxl

I am using the latest python flask, openpyxl & MySQL for one of my personal projects. Things were going really well until now, and I have been struggling to store the data from Excel to MySQL table using SQLAlchemy.

Let me share the code snippets here,

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def view_stocks():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.files['file']
        print("file name")
        print(uploaded_file)
        print(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'])
        if uploaded_file.filename != '':
            filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
            file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
            if file_ext not in app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS']:
                flash(f'Invalid file extension {file_ext}!', category='danger')
                return render_template('stocks.html')
            print(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH']))
            uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))
            wb = load_workbook(filename=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH']) + filename)
            sheet_object = wb['cashbook']
            cashbook_list = []
            for i, row in enumerate(sheet_object.iter_rows()):
                if i == 0:
                    continue
                cashbook_list.append(tuple([cell.value for cell in row]))
            db.session.bulk_insert_mappings().values(Cashbook, cashbook_list)
            db.session.commit()
```

**Flask SQLAlchemy model**

```
class Cashbook(db.Model, UserMixin):
    cashbook_no = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    cashbook_date = db.Column(Date, nullable=False)
    nature_of_expenses = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=False)
    details = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=False)
    payments = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=True)
    receipts = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=True)
    closing_balance = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Cashbook, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

**This is table in Excel**

[image]

Problem 1: From Excel, we are reading it as a tuple and then I am using the following code to insert if `db.session.bulk_insert_mappings().values(Cashbook, cashbook_list)` but bulk_insert_mappings accept the Model name and dictionary, not a tuple.

Problem 2: The first object is date in Excel whenever we are trying to access getting a following error `'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable`

May I know how to insert tuples directly in the SQLAlchemy table or is there any other easy way to read Excel values as customer object(Cashbook) then we shall insert the object directly into the database as well as the date issue.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You might try using pandas' [read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to pull the table into a DataFrame and then use `to_sql()` to upload it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response @GordThompson. do we have any other examples? Documentation is very lame

Comment: @GordThompson exactly how to read the data as object and then do bulk insert

Comment: In its simplest form, [this](https://pastebin.com/y3rPxiDC) works for me.

Comment: @GordThompson This is so elegant...Thank you so much. but we cannot give custom column name?

Comment: You can [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the DataFrame columns to match those of the table into which you are inserting.

Comment: @GordThompson actually in readExcel it self we have cols and skip rows which did the trick